# Logging user activity in web app

Tags: java, servlets, logging, spring-security, dwr

I'd like to be able to log user activities in a web app. I'm currently using log4j which works well for logging errors etc, but I'm unsure what the best approach is to log the user, executed servlet method, and method params. I'm using spring security for the authentication.

A typical servlet could look like:

```
public class BankAccountServlet {
    @RequestMapping("/deposit")
    public void deposit(double amount) {
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping("/checkBalance")
    public double checkBalance() {
        ...
    }
}
```

If there are two users, foo and bar, where foo checks his balance and bar deposits two sums of cash 10.00 and 5.00. I'd like the logs to look like:

```
01/01/1970 23:59:59 - foo - checkBalance
02/01/1970 23:59:59 - bar - deposit - 10.00
02/01/1970 23:59:59 - bar - deposit - 5.00
```

If anyone could offer some advice I'd really appreciate their help.

Comment: This might be out of context, but if that's a real banking application, I'd stay clear from logging such data, without ensuring sufficient protection for the logs.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple to achieve using MDC/NDC functionality built into Log4J (SLF4J and Logback only support MDC).

### Implementing MDC filter

First, implement a servlet filter that will add username to MDC/NDC. Logback provides convenient [MDCInsertingServletFilter](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/helpers/MDCInsertingServletFilter.html), Spring framework also adds [Log4jNestedDiagnosticContextFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/Log4jNestedDiagnosticContextFilter.html) to the store. Look at them but you will need a custom one like this:

```
public class UserToMdcFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter
{
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        MDC.put("user", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove("user");
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

### Adding MDC value to your logging pattern

Make sure this filter is applied in `web.xml` after Spring security filter. MDC feature is really slick - it will add all values saved in MDC thread-local map to each and every logging statement if requested. In your case, simply add this:

```
%X{user}
```

to your logging [pattern](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

### Unobtrusive logging method parameters/values

Logging method name, parameters and return values is up to you (username will be added automatically), but there are some elegant ways to remove boilerplate logging code completely. Try this Spring built-in aspect:

```
<bean id="customizableTraceInterceptor" class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor">
    <property name="enterMessage" value="Entering $[methodName]($[arguments])"/>
    <property name="exitMessage" value="Leaving $[methodName](): $[returnValue]"/>
</bean>
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="customizableTraceInterceptor" pointcut="execution(public * BankAccountServlet.*(..))"/>
</aop:config>
```

### Final thoughts

- Look at this thread: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?88890-MDC-Log4j-Filter-with-Spring-Security-3.0.2
- Consider using [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) as a logging library and stick with SLF4J API.

Comment: Are there any examples like this for Log4J2?

Answer (score 0):

I have used log4j in the past in order to log more than just errors. I added INFO tags throughout my code and change the logging level. That way if you decide you no longer need to log those activities you can just change the logging level and you are done. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log in sever logs, Use ServletContext.log() method which uses the container logging mechanism and logs into container logs..