# logging/monitoring user activity in a java web app

Tags: java, logging, monitoring

I have the same requirements (=track the user activity) as this post:

[Logging user activity in web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115858/logging-user-activity-in-web-app)

What I would like to know is:
Is the suggested solution (use MDC/NDC) out of date or would you implement it the same way?
Or should this be solved by using an own monitoring framework (like https://github.com/anotheria/moskito)?

Comment: What the question here? and what all you tried?

Comment: What kind of user activities you would like to monitor?

Comment: i have updated my question - hope it is better now

Comment: you want metrics or not?

Comment: ThreadLocal is used in most of the advanced java frameworks. MDC/NDC is not out of date. MosKito may be more helpful when you need performance analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to understand what you are trying to achieve. If you want to have some kind of AuditLog, which means to know when something happened, why something happened, and who did it, log4j/slf4j etc will be absolutely sufficient. Because you will probably need this data only once and after some weeks and only to answer some questions by the police.

However if you want to know what happens in your application, how many requests this or that components receives, how long do the requests take, how many errors are produced and what happens overall... You need something more powerful than logging framework, and of all open source performance monitoring tools [MoSKito](http://www.moskito.org) is best...

So, if you are interested in knowing what exactly a special user has done - logging is sufficient. If you want to know, what happens in your application - its not.

Comment: thank you - I guess you are right - we have to work out our requirements in detail