# How can i add the rest call in the [%thread] log format instead of https-jsse-nio-9005-exec-2]

Tags: java, rest, logback

Currently, my logs are printing like this below

```
 [2020-06-06 HH:MM:SS] [INFO] [https-nio-9005-exec-2] [com.test.restcall]-[hello world]
```

I need to get the same log like below:

```
[2020-06-06 HH:MM:SS] [INFO] [GET/firstapplication/my-app] [com.test.restcall]-[hello world]
```

Can anyone help me in getting this??

Note: using logback, dropwizard application,

%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35}  - %msg%n

Comment: The duplicate answer [linked up top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116385/5221149) shows how to use a Servlet Filter to log user name. You can easily modify that to capture the HTTP Method + Path instead. Depending on which REST framework you're using, you can use something other than a Servlet Filter, e.g. in Jersey you can use a Request Filter or an Interceptor.

Comment: `%thread` by definition prints the thread-name.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so how where/how do i need to configure to get like that

Comment: See the duplicate.